# Skipping stages in Jenkins pipeline on a Commit but not a PR

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

We are currently using the Jenkins/Groovy pipeline method for CI.

I'm trying to create a single pipeline for building packages and running unit tests on a branch (and let me know if this is bad practice).

The problem is on a commit I don't want to execute my test steps (due to the large number of commits and time to execute the full pipeline), but I still want the packaging stage to run for our manual testers to be able to pull and install on instances.

Is there any way to distinguish between a run for a PR vs a commit in the pipeline steps or in the job configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Using the (assuming github, but theres bitbucket equiv as well)

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin to discover Repositories to build branches and PR's will allow you to fall back on Jenkins ENV variables.

This allows simple if statement to determine if the build is for a branch, or for a PR, as PR's are built on a 'branch' of PR-n
Once a PR is open however, all commits would be built.

https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#github-branch-source

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [changeRequest](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stages) built-in condition from Jenkins.

> Executes the stage if the current build is for a "change request" (a.k.a. Pull Request on GitHub and Bitbucket, Merge Request on GitLab, Change in Gerrit, etc.). When no parameters are passed the stage runs on every change request, for example: when { changeRequest() }.

```
stage('Run only for pull requests to master branch or at the master branch') {
    when {
        anyOf {
            branch 'master'
            changeRequest target: 'master'
        }
    }
    steps {
        // this is a very long step for integration test that we don't want to execute often, but we need to execute before to merge to master
        sh "${mvn} " +
            "clean " +
            "test-compile " +
            "failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify"
    }
}
```